# Generating 3D surface plots with Vega?

Tags: d3.js, plot, vega, vega-lite

A current project requires us to use [Vega Visualization Grammar](https://vega.github.io/vega/) wherever possible and otherwise fall back to D3.js. 3D-surface plots are not part of the   [Vega's gallery of examples](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/), however [Vega Documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/extensibility/) makes me optimistic that we could create our own graph representations. **Could somebody advise me how to do generate 3D surface plots with Vega?** Any tutorial you suggest? Or maybe even a brief recipe assuming that I have a data set of say a few 100 `(x,y,z)` tuples?

**Edit:** The goal is quasi-static graphics with linear-interpolation between the points, in R we would probably do it like with a [wireframe](https://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-surface-plots/).

Obviously, I extensively used search engines, but see many results on astronomic research on [α Lyrae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega).

Comment: don't search for `Vega` but `3D transformations` and you get tons of links to game development, OpenGL, .....

Comment: You have much more in using `WebGL`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the issue is that `plotly` or `WebGL` are considered too much. A nice example what I am after is e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implied_volatility_surface

Comment: Somebody has to do the math, it is you completely or you let some of the tricky math done by WebGL or plotly. If plotly can draw such a graph easily why not use it? Writing plotly in javascript will be a time consuming project.

Comment: There already is a JS version of plot.ly.

Comment: Vega does appear to have unofficial/undocumented 3d visualization support. https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1738 It's not yet clear exactly what is/isn't possible via this functionality, but I'm very excited to find out more about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3D surface plots are not supported by Vega. You might try another library, like [threejs](https://threejs.org/).

Comment: Is in principle possible to contribute to the Vega project by addening a new plot type? Is there any detailed guide on how to do that?

Comment: threejs is a scene graph library on top of WebGL

Comment: Just to be sure@jakevdp, is it still the case as of 2022?

Comment: @B--rian Of course you could contribute to Vega, but given that adding a new type of plot is a very involved process, you're unlikely to find a guide that will walk you through all the steps.